# Combining functions in R

Tags: r, function

I'm doing a task but I have no idea how to combine 2 functions so that I get multiple answers from one. I'm doing t.testing and had to write out the function, and then i had to write an if-else loop that states wether the hypotesis will be rejected or not. Both of them work individually but I can't figure out how to merge them so when I run the code I get a numerical answer and a line stating whether the hypotesis will be rejected. For the numerical answer I've got this:

```
osuustesti <- function(x1,x2,n1,n2) {
    ((x1/n1)-(x2/n2))/sqrt((1/n1 + 1/n2)*((x1+x2)/(n1+n2))*(1-((x1+x2)/(n1+n2))))
}
```

And for the line stating what will be done with the hypotesis I've got this:

```
osuustesti2 <- function(x1,x2,n1,n2,alpha) {
    if(abs(((x1/n1)-(x2/n2))/sqrt((1/n1 + 1/n2)*((x1+x2)/(n1+n2))*(1-((x1+x2)/(n1+n2)))))> qnorm(alpha/2,lower.tail=FALSE)) {
        cat("Nollahypoteesi hylätään")} else{cat("Nollahypoteesi hyväksytään")
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to combine them into 1 so when I run the code I get both the numerical value and the line... I tried to copying both functions and adding them with & but that didn't work at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
osuustesti <- function(x1, x2, n1, n2, alpha = 0.05) {
    numer <- x1 / n1 - x2 / n2 
    denum <- sqrt((1 / n1 + 1 / n2) * 
                  ((x1 + x2) / ( n1 + n2)) * 
                  (1 - ( x1 + x2) / (n1 + n2)))
    result <- numer / denum

    if (result > qnorm(alpha / 2, lower.tail = FALSE)) {
        cat("Nollahypoteesi hylätään\n")
    } else {
        cat("Nollahypoteesi hyväksytään\n")
    }
    return(result)
}
```

I save result to `result` object, then compare it to `alpha`, `cat` the string and in the end use `return()` to return result from the function.

Comment: Interesting! So there is no shortcut to just take 2 different functions and combine their results? Also I should learn to write my functions the way you did so it wouldn't look so bad in the code!